# building python-boost hello world on Mac OS X with Homebrew - Makefile vs. Resolution

Tags: python, c++, macos, makefile, boost-python

While not directly an explicit question - I am trying to make a post that addresses some of the bizarre issues encountered when trying to install `boost-python` as a novice

The post is based on [this example](https://feralchicken.wordpress.com/2013/12/07/boost-python-hello-world-example-using-cmake/) which can directly be obtained by

```
wget https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/508241/wordpress/BoostPythonHelloWorld.tar.gz
tar xf BoostPythonHelloWorld.tar.gz
cd BoostPythonHelloWorld
cmake .
make
./test.py
```

A bold but accurate claim is that I have systematically read *all* relevant google search results for `"boost-python hello world Makefile"` (there aren't that many) and through every SO post that comes up in a search for `boost-python hello world Makefile`. The methods I have tried are obviously fairly exhaustive and I have also tried a large number of examples.

### Issues

My best success with a `Makefile` is at the end of this post for readability. These issues are largely based on that.

- The first is reasonably trivial that `brew install boost-python` will install boost somewhere like `/usr/Cellar/boost/1.61.0/` and this can cause most online resources to fail unless it is explicitly linked
- `Mac OS X` comes with native python. Installing `homebrew install python` as most users will have done, will cause `cmake` to link to native python by mistake.
- We must explicitly link the `python` library `libpython2.7.dylib`
- There was some combination of the below `Makefile` that actually compiled to `100%` but then I had the following, which seemed to come from `boost-python` failing to link to `cpython`:

  ```
   [ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/greet.dir/greet.cpp.o
   [ 50%] Linking CXX shared library libgreet.dylib
   [ 50%] Built target greet
   [ 75%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/greet_ext.dir/greet_ext.cpp.o
   [100%] Linking CXX shared library greet_ext.dylib
   Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
     "_PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords", referenced from:
  ```

  I changed my `Makefile` without cleaning my `Build/` a few times and by the time I realised I had forgotten to purge the old files I have changed my `Makefile` too much to recreate this level of success
- Removing `SHARED` compiles without error but I cannot import as I should be able to with `import greet_ext`

### `Makefile`

```
project( BoostPythonHelloWorld )
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)

set(Boost_REALPATH          ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS   ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS
    regex
    filesystem
    system
    thread
    python
    chrono
    date_time
    atomic
    REQUIRED)
# include extras
message("")
message("CMAKE finds wrong dirs of Boost (Mac OSX default)...")
message("... Include Include of boost: " ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS "/usr/Cellar/boost/1.61.0/")
set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS "/usr/Cellar/boost/1.61.0/include")
message("... Actual Include of boost: " ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}} )

find_package(PythonLibs 2.7 REQUIRED)
message("")
message("CMAKE finds wrong dirs of Python (Mac OSX default)...")
message("... Include dirs of Python: " ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
message("... Libs of Python: " ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES} )
set(PYTHON_LIBRARIES "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/libpython2.7.dylib")
set(PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7")
message("... Actual Include: " ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
message("... Actual lib: " ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES} )

# Build our library
add_library( greet SHARED greet.cpp )

# Define the wrapper library that wraps our library
add_library( greet_ext SHARED greet_ext.cpp )
target_link_libraries( greet_ext ${Boost_LIBRARIES} greet )
# don't prepend wrapper library name with lib
set_target_properties( greet_ext PROPERTIES PREFIX "" )
```

#### `Makefile` output

using the command: `rm -rf Build; mkdir Build; cd Build; cmake ..; make;` in the directory `BoostPythonHelloWorld` I obtain:

```
CMAKE finds wrong dirs of Boost (Mac OSX default)...
... Include Include of boost: /usr/local/include
... Actual Include of boost: /usr/Cellar/boost/1.61.0/include}
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/libpython2.7.dylib (found suitable version "2.7.10", minimum required is "2.7") 

CMAKE finds wrong dirs of Python (Mac OSX default)...
... Include dirs of Python: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/python2.7
... Libs of Python: /usr/lib/libpython2.7.dylib
... Actual Include: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7
... Actual lib: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/libpython2.7.dylib
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/alex/Downloads/BoostPythonHelloWorld/Build
Scanning dependencies of target greet
[ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/greet.dir/greet.cpp.o
[ 50%] Linking CXX shared library libgreet.dylib
clang: error: invalid argument '-bundle' not allowed with '-dynamiclib'
make[2]: *** [libgreet.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/greet.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Add PYTHON_LIBRRARIES to your target_link_libraries as well

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly address the `Makefile` issues but is rather to make other python users will be aware of my breakthrough that a `Makefile` was not necessary.

I'll still accept any answers leading to a fix with the `Makefile` attempt.

Using a different example `hello_ext.cpp`:

```
char const* greet()
{
   return "hello, world";
}

#include <boost/python.hpp>

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello_ext)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("greet", greet);
}
```

I was able to get it to import into python using this `setup.py` taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21751764/4013571):

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension

hello_ext = Extension(
    'hello_ext'
    ,sources=['hello_ext.cpp']
    ,libraries=['boost_python-mt']     # for python 3 use 'boost_python3-mt'
    # you may also want to add these
    ,extra_compile_args=['-std=c++11','-stdlib=libc++']
    ,extra_link_args=['-stdlib=libc++']
    )

setup(
    name='hello-world',
    version='0.1',
    ext_modules=[hello_ext])
```

building with: `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` I was able to import successfully!

```
In [1]: ls
Makefile       build/         hello_ext.cpp  hello_ext.so*  setup.py

import hello_ext
hello_ext.greet()

## -- End pasted text --
Out[2]: 'hello, world'
```

As a side note: The following are in my `~/.bash_profile`

```
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH="$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH:/usr/include/python2.7/"
export BOOST_ROOT='/usr/Cellar/boost/1.61.0/'
export BOOST_INC="/usr/Cellar/boost/1.61.0/include"
export BOOST_LIB="/usr/Cellar/boost/1.61.0/lib"
```

Comment: If I try that, the compilation generates `clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ with a minimum deployment target of OS X 10.9 [-Wdeprecated]`. Then, in python `import hello_ext` fails with `ImportError: dlopen(/Users/walter/code/test/hello_ext.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyClass_Type`.